# PHP - foreach returning duplicate entries

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I have a foreach loop returning duplicate entries from a array string without  duplicates inside it.

The code:

```
$a = [];
        $b = [];
        foreach($categories['results'][0]['parameters'] as $key => $value) {
            if(in_array($value['code'], $input_valid_names)) {
                if($value['type'] == 'input') {
                    $a = $value['code'];
                    $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
                }
                if($value['type'] == 'select'){
                    $a = $value['code'];
                    $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
                }
                if($value['type'] == 'checkbox' && !empty($PostData[$value['code']])){
                    $a = $value['code'];
                    $b = 'Sim';
                }
                $param[] = [$a => $b];
            }
        }
```

Any idea why its doing it? Made several debug but no clue...

Comment: Can you show the result of `var_dump($param[])`? (you can edit your question)

Comment: please provide some sample data also

Comment: Well there is a difference between both you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp

Comment: I know the difference but here no mismatch here clearly known that we are matching `string` and `string` @Exterminator BTW i was reading the same post when you commented about that post hihihihihi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when `$value['type']` not equal for any `if` statement your code sets in `$param` previous `$a/$b` value. Try this:

```
    $param = [];
    foreach($categories['results'][0]['parameters'] as $key => $value) {
        $a = false;
        $b = false;
        if(in_array($value['code'], $input_valid_names)) {
            if($value['type'] == 'input') {
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
            }
            if($value['type'] == 'select'){
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
            }
            if($value['type'] == 'checkbox' && !empty($PostData[$value['code']])){
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = 'Sim';
            }
            if($a and $b){
                $param[] = [$a => $b];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = '';
    $b = '';
    $param = array();
    foreach ($categories['results'][0]['parameters'] as $key => $value) {
        if (in_array($value['code'], $input_valid_names)) {
            if ($value['type'] === 'input') {
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
            }else if ($value['type'] === 'select') {
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = $PostData[$value['code']];
            }else if ($value['type'] === 'checkbox' && !empty($PostData[$value['code']])) {
                $a = $value['code'];
                $b = 'Sim';
            }
            $param[] = [$a => $b];
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think nothing will change because `value['type']== 'input'` and `value['type']==='input'` both are `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, putting:

```
$param[] = [$a => $b];
```

inside every if validation.
No more duplicate values inside $param array.

Comment: You make not a necessary duplication of the code. check this and just copy this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52311074/5907412

Comment: Hi Andre, it seems Dmytro answered your question. If that is the case you can delete your answer and accept his.

Comment: Many Thanks... Right answer checked :)